# query result based loop syntax in if condition

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

I am new to PGSQL and trying to start a loop in database function that iterates on the basis of query result as shown below.  I am using 8.2 version.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo(text)
RETURNS SETOF activityhistoryview
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
    AS $_$
DECLARE
tilldate ALIAS for $1;
actrec revpro_500.activity%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    IF tilldate != '' THEN
        FOR actrec IN
            SELECT activity.* from revpro_500.activity WHERE activity.householdid = 950
        LOOP
    ELSE
        FOR actrec IN
            SELECT activity.* from revpro_500.activity WHERE activity.householdid = 500
        LOOP    
    END IF;

        BEGIN
        /* rest code goes here */
        END
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;$_$;
```

After executing above function, I am getting below error.

**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ELSE"**

What I am missing here?

Comment: If you are new to PostgreSQL, then why use version 8.2 which is already 5 years past its EOL? PG 8.2 is older than the iPhone!

Comment: @patric: this is an lagacy product which I am working upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not nest loop queries like that. Instead, first evaluate what you want to do with `tilldate`, then make a single loop query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo(tilldate text) RETURNS SETOF activityhistoryview
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS $_$
DECLARE
    actrec revpro_500.activity%ROWTYPE;
    hhid integer;
BEGIN
    IF tilldate != '' THEN
        hhid = 950;
    ELSE
        hhid = 500;
    END IF;

    FOR actrec IN
        SELECT * from revpro_500.activity WHERE householdid = hhid
    LOOP
        BEGIN -- Do you really need a transaction block? If not, remove BEGIN/END
        -- rest code goes here
        END
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;$_$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in most languages you can't have your control structures overlapping, so on the line before the `ELSE` you open a `LOOP`, but do not close it before the `ELSE`, so the `ELSE` doesn't have an attached `IF` paired to it.

You can put the `IF`/`ELSE` block inside the loop, or outside it, but not overlapping.

Example:

```
-- Good
LOOP
    -- some computations
    IF tilldate != '' THEN
        EXIT;  -- exit loop
    ELSE
        -- some computations
    END IF;
END LOOP;

-- Good
IF tilldate != '' THEN
    LOOP
        -- some computations
    END LOOP;
ELSE
    LOOP
        -- some computations
    END LOOP;
END IF;    

-- Bad
IF
    LOOP
        -- some computations
ELSE
    -- some computations
END IF;
END LOOP;
```